# Stripe charge existing customer

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using embed stripe.js

Upon form completion, the form redirects to: `www.mydomain.com/doc-whatever/?action=payment`

This url param fires the serverside code. Abbreviated pseudo code:

```
$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

//check if customer ID exists in the DB.
//returns the stripe customer id of client attached to the document. 
//May or may not be logged in.
$customers_stripe_id = get_customer_stripe_id()

if ( ! $customers_stripe_id ) {

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
   'email' => 'customer@example.com',
   'source'  => $token
  ));

  $customers_stripe_id = $customer_id;

}

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
   'customer' => $customers_stripe_id,
   'amount'   => 5000,
   'currency' => 'usd'
 ));
```

This works just fine, however there is an obvious security issue here. One can simply navigate to `www.mydomain.com/doc-whatever/?action=payment` and if there is stripe customer id stored in the database, the card customer will be charged.

Comment: If you're saying what I think you're saying (that is you want to protect against people navigating to a page through the url) then take a look at the question I asked here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171022/user-cant-navigate-to-webpage-through-the-ui-due-to-permissions-but-are-able-t it has a lot of good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your server-side code should be authorized then, so that for example only a logged in customer himself or an admin could fire that action.